# Function not working on Vista

Tags: javascript, epad

I have this JavaScript function which is working in all the machines I tried except the one that is running on Vista. I am calling this function `onload`. what do you think is wrong with this one.

```
function isePad() {
    var epad;
    epad = window.document.esCapture1.ConnectedDevice;

    if (!epad) {
        alert('Sorry epad either is not Connected or/and drivers are not installed');
    }
}
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean? Does it throw an error or is the result not as expected?

Comment: What interpreter are you using? Windows Script Host?

Comment: What is ePad? A device? A product? A platform? Can you give a link?

Comment: @pekka: http://www.epadlink.com/
@Gumbo: It throws Javascript object expected error
@jball: Windows Script Host

Comment: Well, maybe the ePad is either not connected or/and the drivers are not installed? :) Have you made sure they are? Do your user rights give you access to the device? Can you try running the script as Administrator? From what I hear, Vista is really a PITA rights-wise sometimes. How, when and where do you load this ePad thing? `window.document.esCapture1` is hardly available in WSH by default, it it? Is your question anserwed by jball's answer below (is it a syntax question) or is your device not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esCapture1` probably does not exist - You should check for it first:

```
function isePad() { 
    var epad; 
    if(window.document.esCapture1){
        epad = window.document.esCapture1.ConnectedDevice; 
    }

    if (!epad) { 
        alert('Sorry epad either is not Connected or/and drivers are not installed'); 
    } 
}
```